# Java class for Month Object

Tags: java, class

I'm working on a Java class for a Month object but it does not return the actual month, can you help?

Here is the Private methods class:

```
public class Month
{
private static int numInstantiated = 0;
private int monthNumber = 0;

public Month()
{
    monthNumber = 1;
    numInstantiated++;
}
public Month(int num)
{
    monthNumber = num;
    numInstantiated++;
}

public void setMonth(int newMonth)
{
    monthNumber = newMonth;
}
public int getMonth()
{
    return monthNumber;
}

public String toString()
{
switch(monthNumber)
{
case 1: return "January";
case 2: return "February";
case 3: return "March";
case 4: return "April";
case 5: return "May";
case 6: return "June";
case 7: return "July";
case 8: return "August";
case 9: return "September";
case 10: return "October";
case 11: return "November";
case 12: return "December";
default: return "No month specified";
}
}

}
```

And here is the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseMonth
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    Month m1 = new Month();
    Integer newMonth;

    //kbd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter a numeric representaion of the Month? (ex. 1 for January)");
    newMonth = kbd.nextInt();
    m1.setMonth(newMonth);

    System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " + m1.getMonth());
}
}
```

Thanks in advance -  Fred

Comment: You just made the wrong output. It should be `System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " + m1);`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If not be advised that this problem is alraedy solved.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're calling `getMonth()` which returns an int. You'll want to call `m1.toString()`, which returns the string representation you're trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a perfect opportunity to use an `enum`:

```
enum Month {
  January,
  February,
  March,
  April,
  May,
  June,
  July,
  August,
  September,
  October,
  November,
  December;

  public static Month get(int n) {
    return Month.values()[n-1];
  }

}

public void test() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    System.out.println("Month " + i + " = " + Month.get(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! It's a very good idea, as you say, it is the perfect opportunity to use enums

Answer (score 0):

try this..

System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " + m1.toString());

in your main class.

Answer (score 0):

You have ovewritten the toString method. If you just call your getMonth method, this one does not call automatically the toString method, so it will return the number of the month.

If you want yo see the name of the month, you must do one of this two options:

Change your getMonth method:

```
public String getMonth()
{
    return this.toString(monthNumber);
}
```

Or in your main method, change the System Out call:

```
System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " + m1.toString(m1.getMonth()));
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Rafa, I changed my getMonth method (option 1) per your instruction but I am getting this error:                                                                                                                                   .\Month.java:28: error: no suitable method found for toString(int)
   return this.toString(monthNumber);
              ^
    method Month.toString() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: Sorry! I wrote rapidly the answer. Evidently is an error, my apologies! You must do: `return this.toString();` Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the final line of your code with this :

```
System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " + m1.toString());
```

In your existing code, `m1.getMonth()` will return you the number of the month. 
Using `m1.toString()` will give the respective String equivalent of the entered Integer number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think all the previous answers are correct and have provided you with a good feedback/answers. There's more than one way to skin a cat. So, I have cleaned up your code a and remove some of the unnecessary method and I have also tested the program to make sure it works for you. Here are the the two classes for you.

```
public class Month {
    private static int numInstantiated = 0;

    public Month() {
        numInstantiated++;
        getMonthTextual(numInstantiated);
    }

    public String getMonthTextual(int monthNumber) {
        switch (monthNumber) {
        case 1:
            return "January";
        case 2:
            return "February";
        case 3:
            return "March";
        case 4:
            return "April";
        case 5:
            return "May";
        case 6:
            return "June";
        case 7:
            return "July";
        case 8:
            return "August";
        case 9:
            return "September";
        case 10:
            return "October";
        case 11:
            return "November";
        case 12:
            return "December";
        default:
            return "No month specified";
        }
    }

}
```

here is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
                Month m1 = new Month();
                Integer newMonth;

                //kbd.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Please enter a numeric representaion of the Month? (ex. 1 for January)");
                newMonth = kbd.nextInt();

                System.out.println("You entered: " + newMonth + ", which is the month of " +   m1.getMonthTextual(newMonth));
            }
            }
```